# Add current Date to Time UTC String and Convert to Device Time

Tags: android, date, time

I have a UTC Time String(05:30:00) add the current date to the String and convert the (UTC DateTime) to (Device Time)

Note: Without using ZoneID

Answer (score 0):

```
String dateStr = "Jul 16, 2013 12:08:59 AM";
SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd, yyyy HH:mm:ss a", Locale.ENGLISH);
df.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
Date date = df.parse(dateStr);
df.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getDefault());
String formattedDate = df.format(date);
```

Note : And don't forget to include the "a" (am/pm marker) instead of the "z" (time zone).

Comment: It works to convert the complete date and time String to UTC first I need to add the current date to the given time String.